# 'C2504 base class undefined' error despite #include and forward declaration?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

How can it be that the following code generates a `C2504: 'GameObject': base class undefined?!` error:

```
#ifndef INCLUDED_PLAYER
#define INCLUDED_PLAYER
#include "GameObject.h"
#include "Game.h"
#include "Bullet.h"
#include <SFML/Window/Keyboard.hpp>

class GameObject;
class Player:
    public GameObject
{ <- Compiler Error
```

Edit: Problem found, for whatever reason I added an unnecessary include in GameObject.h. Removing that include fixed all my problems.

Comment: You only need the include. You do need a complete type to inherit from it.

Comment: My psychic debugging skills tell me that you have a circular inclusion problem (i.e., GameObject.h or one of the headers that it includes includes this header).